# How to show input screen without a UITextField?

Tags: swift, apple-tv

In my project for Apple TV, I need show a input screen arbitrarily, without a `UITextField`. For example, when a user click in `UICell`. But, I only found solutions using `UITextField` or showing `UIAlertController`.

Then, I wrote a code bellow (with workaround) to show input screen:

```
class ShowInput: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var callback: ((String) -> Void)?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        callback?(textField.text!)
        textField.text = ""

        textField.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Then, In view...

```
class CreateGridViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let showInput = ShowInput()

    // ...

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CellConfigInput
        cell.addSubview(showInput)

        showInput.callback = { text in
            cell.labelField.text = text
        }

        showInput.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

But, I want a better solution, with a readable code. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

#### Apple quietly explain how to do it in the doco:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/CreatingaGreatTextInputExperience.html

> Advanced UITextField Keyboards
>
> All of the iOS first responder mechanisms work on tvOS. This allows developers to present a UI, visible **or hidden**, and then make one of the text fields the first responder by calling the becomeFirstResponder method on it. This action causes .. **the keyboard UI without the user having to navigate to a text field** and click on it ..

The secret is **`or hidden`** ...

So that's the answer. Ridiculous, but true.  Just have an invisible text field, and use that.  Call `becomeFirstResponder()` on the invisible text field and away you go.

Answer (score -1):

You can make any standard `UIResponder` subclass you like conform to the `UIKeyInput` protocol and call `becomeFirstResponder()` on it to bring up the keyboard.

Since `UICollectionViewController` is a `UIResponder` subclass, you should be able to make `CreateGridViewController` conform to the key input protocol and avoid the entire text field.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried and I can't to work it. I made to `CellConfigInput` subscribe `UIKeyInput` protocol, and override `canBecomeFocused` to always return true, but, when I call `becomeFirstResponder()`, nothing happens. I also tried with `CreateGridViewController`, and not work too.

Comment: You need to override `canBecomeFirstResponder` instead of `canBecomeFocused` to make this work.

Comment: Yep, I made it too, but not shown the keyboard: https://gist.github.com/brunomacabeusbr/6a196a6293bb429119d49ca2a3757080

Line `cell.becomeFirstResponder()` and `override var canBecomeFocused: Bool { return true }` are called, but, even so, keyboard isn't called.

Comment: Unfortunately this now just doesn't work (this answer is now very old, so it may have worked then).